# How to prevent glitches appear in curses app?

Tags: python, ncurses, tmux, curses

I'm developing app with curses in Python. And few seconds after app starts some glitches appear randomly. 
[image: Normal]
[image: With glitches]

First I thought it's because of tmux and `$TERM` variable, but it is set to `screen-256`. Running app outside tmux also causes this kind of glitch.

Here is the code that initializes [curses screen](https://github.com/stsdc/svs/blob/master/server/widgets/screen.py)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example does this:

```
import curses
from threading import Thread


class Screen(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.maxx = None
        self.maxy = None

self.run()
```

implying that your application could have multiple threads writing to the screen.  But curses is normally not thread-safe, so you'll end up with the threads using theirs - and other threads - values of global or static variables.  It won't work well.

If you want to use curses in a multi-threaded application, you'll have to either ensure that *only one thread uses curses*, or (probably) compile your own copy of the ncurses library which has rudimentary support for re-entrant code, and work within the constraints of *that* configuration.

Further reading:

- [Why does (fill in the blank) happen when I use two threads?](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#multithread) (ncurses FAQ)

Comment: `curses` uses escape code sequences to control the screen, and if those sequences get interrupted with other output the results won't be pretty.

Comment: More than that, the functions which format the escape sequences use static variables, which when two threads are updating them, the result is unpredictable.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Yeah, In main thread I start curses, then I start other threads. Those one  send data via events to their curses windows.